Solve 1-D transient heat transfer equation
I want to solve the 1-D transient heat transfer equation
dT/dt = (k/(rho*cp))*d²T/dy²

Define a 1-D geometry(a line) in y-direction
I.C. : @t=0, temperature of all elements is 25°C
B.C. : The geometry is divided into several elements.
a) the bottom element is exposed to hot roller
-kdT/dt = h(T_roller-T)
b) the upper element is exposed to atmosphere
-k*dT/dt = h(T-T_ambient)
I have already made a model in MATLAB and I want to try the same in python using scipy
So, below are the two approaches, solve_ivp and ode_int
solve_ivp:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
Ny = 51            # Number of spatial grid points
Nt = 5000          # Number of time steps
velocity_x = 0.2   # Line speed in m/s

# Thermal properties of different layers
layer1_thickness = 0.001  # Thickness of layer 1 (meters)
layer1_k = 0.15           # Thermal conductivity of layer 1 (W/m-K)

rho_1 = 1250            # Density of layer 1 (kg/m³)
cp_1 = 1350             # Specific heat capacity of layer 1 (J/kg-K)

T_roller = 150          # Temperature of hot roller (°C)
h_roller = 500          # Convective heattransfer coefficient (W/m²-K)

T_ambient = 25         # Ambient temperature (°C)
h_air = 12             # Convective heat transfer coefficient of air (W/m²-K)

Ly = layer1_thickness

# Discretization in space
ny1 = int(np.ceil(layer1_thickness / Ly * Ny))
y = np.linspace(0, Ly, ny1)

dia_roller = 0.8
contact_angle = 180
y_1 = np.pi * dia_roller * contact_angle / 360
y_2 = 0.3

# Discretization in time
t1 = y_1 / velocity_x
t2 = y_2 / velocity_x
T = t1 + t2
t_eval = np.linspace(0, T, Nt)

# Define the PDE functions
#Definition of 1-D Transient pde: dT/dt = (k/(rho*cp))*d²T/dy²
def pdefun(t, u, icfun, bcfun):
    dudy = np.gradient(u, y)
    c = rho_1 * cp_1
    f = layer1_k * dudy
    s = np.zeros_like(u)
    return c * f + s

#At t=0, defining the temperature of all elements to 25°C
def icfun(y):
    return initial_temperature * np.ones_like(y)

#Defining boundary conditions
def bcfun(t, u):
    ul = u[0] #Temperature of the first element/bottom
    ur = u[-1]#Temperature of the last element/top
    if t <= t1:
        pl = -h_air * (ul - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_roller * (ur - T_roller)
        qr = 1
    else:
        pl = -h_air * (ul - T_ambient)
        ql = 1
        pr = h_air * (ur - T_ambient)
        qr = 1
    return np.array([pl, ql, pr, qr])

# Solve the PDE
initial_temperature = 25
initial_condition = icfun(y)
sol = solve_ivp(pdefun, (0, T), initial_condition, args=(icfun, bcfun), method='BDF', atol=1e-4, rtol=1e-4, t_eval=t_eval)
u = sol.y.T
print("u.shape =", u.shape)

temperature_first = u[:, 0]     # Extract temperatures of the first element (first column of u) / unterfläche / bottom layer
temperature_last = u[:, -1]     # Extract temperatures of the last element (last column of u) / oberfläche / upper layer
print(temperature_last.shape)
print(temperature_first)

(5000,)
[ 25.          24.99959522  24.99919044 ... 252.24020125 252.4068531
 252.57359168]

The temperature of the first and last element is not showing proper behaviour. The temperature of all of the elements change at the same rate:

ode_int:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Spatial domain
N = 100  # Number of spatial grid points
y = np.linspace(0, 0.001, N)  # Spatial domain [0, 0.001]
dy = y[1] - y[0]  # Spatial step size


def rhs(u, t, alpha, layer1_k, T_roller, h_roller, h_air, T_ambient):
    """
    Right-hand side function for the system of ODEs.
    """
    dudt = np.zeros_like(u)
    for i in range(1, N-1):
        dudt[i] = alpha * (u[i+1] - 2*u[i] + u[i-1]) / dy**2 #Definition of RHS of pde using central difference scheme

    # Left boundary condition (roller)
    #dudt[0] = (h_roller * (T_roller - u[0]) + layer1_k * (u[1] - u[0]) / dy) / (layer1_k / dy + h_roller)
    dudt[0] = (h_roller * (T_roller - u[0]) + layer1_k * (u[1] - u[0]) / dy) / (layer1_k / dy + h_roller)

    # Right boundary condition (convective heat transfer)
    #dudt[-1] = (layer1_k * (u[-2] - u[-1]) / dy - h_air * (u[-1] - T_ambient)) / (layer1_k / dy)
    
    dudt[-1] = (h_air * (T_ambient - u[-1]) - layer1_k * (u[-1] - u[-2]) / dy) / (layer1_k / dy)



    return dudt

def init_cond(y):
    """
    Initial condition, constant temperature of 25°C
    """
    return 25 * np.ones_like(y)

#def boundary_cond(u, t, layer1_k, T_roller, h_roller, h_air, T_ambient):
    """
    #Boundary conditions with convective heat transfer
    """
    # Apply convective boundary condition
    #u[0] = (h_roller * T_roller * dy + layer1_k * u[1]) / (layer1_k + h_roller * dy)
    #u[-1] = (h_air * T_ambient * dy + layer1_k * u[-2]) / (layer1_k + h_air * dy)
    
    #return u

# Initial condition
u0 = init_cond(y)

# Parameters
layer1_k = 0.15
rho_1 = 1250            # Density of layer 1 (kg/m³)
cp_1 = 1350             # Specific heat capacity of layer 1 (J/kg-K)
alpha = layer1_k / (rho_1 * cp_1)  # Thermal diffusivity
T_roller = 150
h_roller = 500
h_air = 12
T_ambient = 25

tmax = 8.0   # Maximum time
t = np.linspace(0, tmax, 100)  # Time points

# Solve using odeint
sol = odeint(rhs, u0, t, args=(alpha, layer1_k, T_roller, h_roller, h_air, T_ambient),)
print(sol[0,:])

[25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25.
 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25.
 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25.
 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25.
 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25.
 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25. 25.]
 
print(sol[-1,:])

[51.87831423 51.50159068 51.12809132 50.75778984 50.39065982 50.02667464
 49.66580758 49.30803177 48.95332018 48.60164567 48.25298093 47.90729856
 47.56457098 47.22477051 46.88786932 46.55383949 46.22265292 45.89428144
 45.56869671 45.24587031 44.92577367 44.60837813 44.2936549  43.98157508
 43.67210966 43.36522953 43.06090544 42.75910809 42.45980803 42.16297572
 41.86858153 41.57659574 41.2869885  40.9997299  40.71478992 40.43213847
 40.15174533 39.87358025 39.59761285 39.32381269 39.05214924 38.7825919
 38.51510999 38.24967274 37.98624934 37.72480888 37.4653204  37.20775285
 36.95207514 36.69825611 36.44626452 36.19606909 35.94763849 35.7009413
 35.45594609 35.21262134 34.97093551 34.730857   34.49235415 34.25539529
 34.01994866 33.78598252 33.55346503 33.32236437 33.09264863 32.86428592
 32.63724429 32.41149177 32.18699636 31.96372603 31.74164874 31.52073242
 31.30094499 31.08225434 30.86462835 30.64803491 30.43244186 30.21781705
 30.00412832 29.79134351 29.57943046 29.368357   29.15809094 28.94860014
 28.73985243 28.53181565 28.32445765 28.11774629 27.91164946 27.70613502
 27.5011709  27.29672501 27.09276528 26.88925969 26.6861762  26.48348284
 26.28114763 26.07913865 25.87742399 25.67597177]

The temperature of the first element is not changing although it is in contact with hot roller and the temperature of the last element is decreasing linearly.
Could someone please help how to resolve the error?
Thanks in advance.

You're not enforcing any boundary conditions in your first code.

Thankyou @jared for the reply. I have written bcfun and included it in the arguments for solve_ivp. Could you please tell me the correct way to enforce the boundary conditions?

You passed bcfun to pdefun, but you never actually use it.

@jared - I am afraid that I do not know the correct way to use it. Could you please tell me how to implement it?

You never call the function. I haven't checked if the function is right, but you'll at least need to call it to use it.
